# Engine starter just won't stop starting

Tags: electrical, toyota, starter

I have a 98 Toyota privia and upon starting it the starter just keeps going. This only occurs in drive and neutral. The vehicle also starts in any gear. When I start in park the starter keeps spinning until I shift then it stops: same as neutral. Also if I nudge the shifter arm on the transaxle it stops.

I've already put in shims with no effect.

Comment: This sounds like something is probably wrong with your PCM, something electronic is clearly messed up because in no other way are the range selector and the starter connected. Possibly have a shop test the computer and see if it needs replacing.

Comment: It had a chip for vehicle disable... The ones that you plug in. But someone bypassed it already... I think that's why it starts in any gear now... But the starter continuing to turn is the bigger problem

Comment: It seems like it's getting stuck in the spin of the flywheel... I was researching on a part called a "parking pawl" but from what I can decipher that would make the vehicle not say put in park...

Comment: Is the gear shift lever on this car mounted on the steering column? The fact that the starter stops starting if you nudge it tells me that the problem is with the ignition switch not returning back to the "On" position

Comment: Not the shifter on column... I actually got under the van and moved the arm on the transaxle itself.... But I will recheck ignition switch...

Answer (score 7):

Two possible failed parts: The ignition switch or the starter relay. The ignition switch would be either not returning to run or has failed electrically. The relay would have to be stuck on or commanded on by the Security ECU. The security system is not supposed to turn on the starter only stop it from working. It is the least likely failure.